# JavaScript: Detect form submission completion

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, submit

I have a form in an iframe and submit it. How can I tell when the submission completes? I'm using jQuery to submit the form but don't think there's a callback:

$("#myForm").submit();
// how to attach event to submission complete?

Answer (score 1):

Submission of the form will redirect you to the next page.

But you can always try the ajax function

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Adding callback is as easy as

```
 $.ajax({
   url: "page.php",
   success: function() {
      doWhateverYouWant();
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you submit a form, it goes to the next page, so there's nothing else that executes on that page.

Comment: If it's in an iframe, the iframe goes to the next page. Therefore, can I detect when the iframe page changes to detect submission completion?

Comment: @JQueeeer if it all happens on the same domain, yes.