# jquery/javascript to detect when form submission completes in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, iframe

I believe I have a similar problem to this person:

[JavaScript: Detect form submission completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629588/javascript-detect-form-submission-completion)

I have a form in an iframe.  When the form completes an http post, i want to capture the returning data and do something with it.  Is there an event handler to detect when a form in an iframe completes an http post?

Comment: Can you show us any part of your use case? There are a few potential issues with cross domain iframe stuff (not sure if this is cross domain)

Comment: I'm working in the same domain. So far diodeus solution works on all my browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a new page is being loaded (a non-AJAX submit) you can hook into the Iframe's `onload` event for this purpose.