# JavaScript: Detect form submission completion - Further

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I tried to comment on the [existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629588/javascript-detect-form-submission-completion), however I cannot until I have at least 50 'Reputation'.

The question I have is very much the same but my form submits to it's self. I wanted to use JavaScript to detect form data and display it if present, but inset a file if not.

The default action is to insert one of several 'Inserts'. Originally I had the form post to a separate ASP classic processor, but I want it all contained on the same ASP document.
In psudo, I want `{If Form then Print Data Else Print 'Welcome' insert)`.
My psudo above is more *VBScriptish*, but it's a JavaScript function I want `(If (Form.Data==True){Do Nothing}else{SetInset('Welcome.asp');)`
I do hope that's a readable question. As I say, much the same question as above link. I'm just kinda trying to justify the question.

```js
<body onload="goSec();AutoRun()">
    function AutoRun(){ 
        setAppDiv('AboutUs.asp', 'apDiv1'); 
    }
    function chkQryInsert() {
        var z=document.location.search; 
        var zx=z.substr(1); 
        var params = {}, queries, temp, i, l;
        // Split into key/value pairs 
        queries = zx.split("&");
        // Convert the array of strings into an object
        for ( i = 0, l = queries.length; i < l; i++ ) { 
            temp = queries[i].split('='); 
            params[temp[0]] = temp[1]; 
            if (temp[0]=='Insert'){ 
                setAppDiv(temp[1],'apDiv1'); 
            }
            else{ 
                setAppDiv('AboutUs.asp', 'apDiv1'); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The gist is;
<body onload="goSec();AutoRun()">
function AutoRun(){
    setAppDiv('AboutUs.asp', 'apDiv1');
}
 
function chkQryInsert(){
 var z=document.location.search;
 var zx=z.substr(1);
 
 var params = {}, queries, temp, i, l;

  // Split into key/value pairs
  queries = zx.split("&");  
    // Convert the array of strings into an object
    for ( i = 0, l = queries.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        temp = queries[i].split('=');
        params[temp[0]] = temp[1];
  if (temp[0]=='Insert'){
   setAppDiv(temp[1],'apDiv1');
  }else{
   setAppDiv('AboutUs.asp', 'apDiv1');
  }
     }
}

Answer (score 0):

Why not intercept the post  using a button and process your answers before posting back to the server, makes more sense.

Just set the button's `onClick` event to the name of a JavaScript function.  In the JavaScript function you can include a `document.forms["myform"].submit();`.

To take this a step further you could also include [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419398/reload-html-table-data-after-database-entry-deleted/28430525#28430525) to allow a level of Ajax like functionality, loading an ASP partial page into a particular `div`.

**-- EDIT --**

Also, consider best practice when you want to join different forms together - is it really worthwhile doing that? I always separate my mark-up and script from each other; it makes it immeasurably more readable.

Comment: Hi..
Thanks for that, that's really sweet code.
Sorry so long in replying, I've been working last few nights.